# Error when reusing karate features with multithreading

Tags: testing, karate

The following code works fine with a single thread:

```
 * def validateAricle = 'file:features/Articles.feature@validateArticle'  
 * def articles = {"id": 12}
 * call read(validateArticle) articles
```

but having more than one thread I get the following error

```
Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[pool-5-thread-1,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.
```

This error can be reproduced from version 1.0.1 (it also happens to me in version 1.0.0). Before updating to version 1.0.0 I had no problems reusing features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we hope we have fixed this in the `develop` branch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1558

The best thing you can do now (and to help expedite a release) is to follow the developer guide, build from source and then verify that it works for your edge case: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

If not, it is very important that you follow this process to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

And I hope that this can be a reminder to everyone that please test the RC versions that we [spend so much time on releasing](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1359010765219393538) (a few months for 1.X).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. Works for me. I had been using RCs but unfortunately I was working with only one thread due to an issue in the application I am testing

Comment: @Corleone when you say `works for me` just wanted to make sure that you tested with the version built from source

Comment: Yes, it works using the version built from source

Comment: I have downgraded to version 0.9.6 to be able to use "feature reuse with parallelism". I will test when a new version is deployed

Comment: The version v1.1.0.RC2 has solved all the problems I had with parallelization and reuse of features